# PHP form type file - If no image is selected, don't update row in database

Tags: php, pdo

I am designing a CMS with PHP PDO for user to update there information, this part I am letting the user change there business image, which will upload to the server and also to database through PHPMyAdmin.

With this I can upload the image and it will replace its value on the database as well fine. What I am having trouble with is when the user just wants to update other information (Not the image) and nothing else, the system submits the image value and replaces the row within database with no value (Blank upload) in the related row? As I would like it to not effect this row, if no image was uploaded.

I have been looking at `if ($_FILES['image']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE)` but not luck, but I think i am in the right area.

**HTML**

```
<form action='edit_account.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<h4>Business Image</h4>
<input type='file' name='image' id='fileToUpload' >
<input type='submit' value='Update Account' />
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_FILES['image'])) {
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $target_dir = "images/users/$username/";
            $target_file = $target_dir.basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
            $upload0K = 1;
            $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

            if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                $check = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
                if($check !== false) {
                    echo "<p>File is an image - ".$check["mime"]."</p>";
                    $upload0K = 1;
                } else {
                    echo "<p>File is not an image</p>";
                    $upload0K = 0;
                }
            }

            //if (file_exists($target_file)) {
                //echo "<p>Sorry, file already exists.</p>";
                //$upload0K = 0;
            //}

            if ($_FILES['image']['size'] > 5000000) {
                echo "<p>Sorry, your file is too large.</p>";
                $upload0K = 0;
            }
            ///
            if ($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
                echo "<p>Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG and GIF files are allowed.</p>";
                $upload0K = 0;
            }

            //if(!isset($_FILES['image']) || $_FILES['image']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) {
                //echo "Error no file selected"; 
            //}

            ///
            if ($upload0K == 0) {
                echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
            }

            else {
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_file)) {
                    echo "<p>The file ". basename( $_FILES["image"]["name"])."has been uploaded.</p>";
                } else {
                    echo "<p>Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.</p>";
                }
              }
            }
```

**SQL Insert**

```
$query_params = array( 
            ':email' => $_POST['email'],
            ':username' => $_POST['username'], 
            ':name' => $_POST['name'],
            ':image' => $_FILES['image']['name'],
            ':description' => $_POST['description'], 
            ':moderatedcheck' => $moderatedcheck, 
            ':user_id' => $_SESSION['user']['id']
        ); 

$query = " UPDATE users SET email = :email, username = :username, name = :name, image = :image, description = :description, moderatedcheck = :moderatedcheck";
```

Comment: When no image is selected, `$_FILES['image']` should not be set. Just check whether the var is set or not, and when updating the row in the db just don't set the _image_ column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best and correct way of doing this is by judging the image Error value, An error value of 4 indicates that no file was uploaded. Other tests of the name of the file or other attributes are somewhat imprecise.

```
$imageFile = $_FILES['image'];
if ($imageFile['error'] != 4) {
///this code only runs if a file has been given.
}
```

## update

> I have been looking at if ($_FILES['image']['error'] ===
>   UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) but not luck, but I think i am in the right area.

The `$_FILES['image']['error']` is the correct thing to check but this value is a numeric value NOT a text value. See if checking if  `$_FILES['image']['error'] == 4` works better.

## Update 2

Replace `if(isset($_FILES['image'])) {` in your file with:

```
if ($_FILES['image']['error'] != 4)}{
```

This will then only run the following code if there is a file given, although there may still be errors such as filesize etc.

Also SQL insert:

Replace original with:

```
$query_params = array( 
            ':email' => $_POST['email'],
            ':username' => $_POST['username'], 
            ':name' => $_POST['name'],
            ':description' => $_POST['description'], 
            ':moderatedcheck' => $moderatedcheck, 
            ':user_id' => $_SESSION['user']['id']
        ); 
$query = " UPDATE users SET email = :email, username = :username, name = :name, description = :description, moderatedcheck = :moderatedcheck";
```

and add a qualifier:

```
    if ($_FILES['image']['error'] == 0 ){
       $query_params[':image'] = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$query = " UPDATE users SET email = :email, username = :username, name = :name, image = :image, description = :description, moderatedcheck = :moderatedcheck";
    }
```

this will then only add the filename data to the insert array if the file is i) present and ii) not with an error. Alternatively saving the file to the database if it *does* have an error will probably be rather pointless, but would be done replacing that if statement with `if ($_FILES['image']['error'] != 4 )` .

Comment: I do appreciate your help, I'm not sure how to use your code within mine I gave it go and im still getting the same results, can you give me a example of how to implement this with mine, thanks

Comment: @magi4000 I should add the "qualifier" would appear directly after your $query_params array and will add the file if it is uploaded ok.

Comment: Okay, I have implement what you have provided and adapted it, but when I try to run it I get this error.

Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens.

Comment: ah I missed that, you also need to update your `$query` string as well, @magi4000 . I hope you understand PHP enough to do this youself?

Comment: This has fix my problem, Thank you so much I do appreciate your help ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Your Sql can be built dynamicly, define a variable like `$imageSql = '';` at the start of the code, when `$_FILES['image']` issetted overwrite your `$imageSql = ', image = :image';` and your `$query_params[':image'] = $_FILES['image']['name']` and lastly your query will be like :
`$query = " UPDATE users SET email = :email, username = :username, name = :name".$imageSql.", description = :description, moderatedcheck = :moderatedcheck";`

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
   if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"])){

        //query to update the data with the image

    }else{
       //query to update the data without the image
}
```